# Laravel eloquent query groupBy category with sum and sortBy sum

Tags: laravel, sorting, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I have 3 related tables:

Table category :

```
+-----+---------------+
| id  | nama_kategori |
+-----+---------------+
| 1   | Sayur         |
| 2   | daging        |
| 3   | buah          | 
+-----+---------------+
```

Table Barang

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| id  | nama_barang | id_kategori |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | Sayur 1     | 1           |  
| 2   | Sayur 2     | 1           |   
| 3   | Daging Ayam | 2           |   
| 4   | Apple       | 3           |   
| 5   | Banana      | 3           |      
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

Table barang_keluar

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
| id  | tgl_keluar  | id_barang | jml_bk  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 1   | 02-03-2021  | 1         |   200   |
| 2   | 04-03-2021  | 2         |   100   |
| 3   | 12-03-2021  | 1         |   100   |
| 4   | 15-03-2021  | 3         |   500   |
| 5   | 20-03-2021  | 2         |   100   |
| 6   | 25-03-2021  | 1         |   100   |
| 6   | 25-03-2021  | 4         |   100   |
| 6   | 25-03-2021  | 5         |   100   |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

The query I'm making now looks like this:

```
$kategorix='All';
$bulan = '2021-03';
$bulanx=Carbon::parse($bulan)->format('Y-m');
    
$kategoriy=DB::table('barang_keluar')->join('barang','barang.id','=','barang_keluar.id_barang')
            ->join('kategori','kategori.id','=','barang.id_kategori')
            ->select('barang_keluar.id_barang',
                     'barang.id_kategori',
                     'kategori.nama_kategori',
                      DB::raw('sum(jml_bk) as total'))
             ->where(DB::raw("date_format(tgl_keluar,'%Y-%m')"), '=', $bulanx)
             ->groupBy('id_barang','id_kategori','nama_kategori')
             ->orderBy('tgl_keluar')
             ->orderBy('total')
             ->get();
                    
$barang = $kategoriy->groupBy('id_kategori');
$array = collect($barang)->sort($barang->sum('total'))->reverse()->toArray();
```

and the results I get:

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#939 ▼
      +"id_barang": 1
      +"id_kategori": 1
      +"nama_kategori": "Sayur 1"
      +"total": "400"
    }
  0 => {#939 ▼
      +"id_barang": 2
      +"id_kategori": 1
      +"nama_kategori": "Sayur 2"
      +"total": "200"
    }
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#943 ▼
      +"id_barang": 3
      +"id_kategori": 2
      +"nama_kategori": "Daging"
      +"total": "500"
    }
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#945 ▼
      +"id_barang": 4
      +"id_kategori": 3
      +"nama_kategori": "Apple"
      +"total": "100"
    }
    0 => {#945 ▼
      +"id_barang": 5
      +"id_kategori": 3
      +"nama_kategori": "Banana"
      +"total": "100"
    }
  ]  
]
```

How to get the result of sort `By('subtotal')` from `groupBy('category_id')`. Please help

I've tried adding query array and sort like this. but the result is still the same as above

```
$array = collect($barang)->sort($barang->sum('total'))->reverse()->toArray();
```

Maybe the blade table example that I made would be like this, but sorted by subtotal of the large - small values. Please help

[image]

Comment: Your question is not super clear, providing sample data and expected output would help. Also worth noting you are not working with Eloquent at all, you are using query builder.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, I hope that the query results can be sorted according to subtotals, from the largest to the smallest values ​​but with the sum of the subtotals of the categories of each item. for example the top 5 big categories of goods. please help

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Below-listed Soluiton

```
    $kategorix='All';
    $bulan = '2021-03';
    $bulanx=Carbon::parse($bulan)->format('Y-m');

    $kategoriy=DB::table('barang_keluar')->join('barang','barang.id','=','barang_keluar.id_barang')
                ->join('kategori','kategori.id','=','barang.id_kategori')
                ->select('barang_keluar.id_barang',
                         'barang.id_kategori',
                         'kategori.nama_kategori',
                          DB::raw('sum(jml_bk) as total'))
                 ->where(DB::raw("date_format(tgl_keluar,'%Y-%m')"), '=', $bulanx)
                 ->groupBy('id_barang','id_kategori','nama_kategori')
                 ->orderBy('tgl_keluar')
                 ->get();

    $barang = $kategoriy->groupBy('id_kategori');


    $category = $barang->map(function ($testcollected) {
        $sum = $testcollected->groupBy('id_kategori')->map(function ($items) {
            return $items->sum('total');
        });

        $testcollected->put('sub_total', $sum);
        return $testcollected;
    });

    print_r($category->toArray());
```